# Transform series and give a name based on the original column

Tags: r

I want to save transformed series with a name based on the original series.

`data$seriesnameLog <- log(data$seriesname)`

The question is how to save the series with the name of the original series plus the suffix (Log in this case).

Using the function
`gsub(" ", "", paste("series$", colnames(series[2]), "Log"))`

I could create a string with the name I need, but I was not able to use the string to name the series. I am also wondering if my solution is the most efficient.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please add a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

data <-
  iris %>%
  select(-Species) %>%
  as_tibble()
data
#> # A tibble: 150 x 4
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1
#> # … with 140 more rows

data %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), log10)) %>%
  rename_all(~paste0(.x, "Log"))
#> # A tibble: 150 x 4
#>    Sepal.LengthLog Sepal.WidthLog Petal.LengthLog Petal.WidthLog
#>              <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>
#>  1           0.708          0.544           0.146         -0.699
#>  2           0.690          0.477           0.146         -0.699
#>  3           0.672          0.505           0.114         -0.699
#>  4           0.663          0.491           0.176         -0.699
#>  5           0.699          0.556           0.146         -0.699
#>  6           0.732          0.591           0.230         -0.398
#>  7           0.663          0.531           0.146         -0.523
#>  8           0.699          0.531           0.176         -0.699
#>  9           0.643          0.462           0.146         -0.699
#> 10           0.690          0.491           0.176         -1    
#> # … with 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>